# Dart - Are sets really unordered?

Tags: dart, set, constants, iterable

From the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets):

> A set in Dart is an unordered collection of unique items.

But if I run this sample code:

```dart
final a = {0, 1, 2};
final b = {2, 1, 0};
for (final i in a) {
  print('a - $i');
}
for (final i in b) {
  print('b - $i');
}
print(a == b);
```

I get the output

```
a - 0
a - 1
a - 2
b - 2
b - 1
b - 0
false
```

The 2 iterables `a` and `b` don't behave the same when looped over and `==` is `false` (But I guess `==` makes sense since the `a` and `b` are not the same instance).

---

However, what I don't understand is if `a` and `b` are constants:

```dart
const a = {0, 1, 2};
const b = {2, 1, 0};
for (final i in a) {
  print('a - $i');
}
for (final i in b) {
  print('b - $i');
}
print(a == b);
```

This yields the same output.

And if I order `b` as `a`:

```dart
const a = {0, 1, 2};
const b = {0, 1, 2};
for (final i in a) {
  print('a - $i');
}
for (final i in b) {
  print('b - $i');
}
print(a == b);
```

It logs:

```
a - 0
a - 1
a - 2
b - 0
b - 1
b - 2
true
```

I'm a bit surprised that `const a = {0, 1, 2}` and `const b = {2, 1, 0}` are not equal. Aren't `const` variable being reused, and aren't `a` and `b` supposed to be equal since sets are unordered?

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know dart, but generally "unordered" is shorthand for "unreliably ordered within or between implementations".

Comment: The default type for Set is ordered by insert order.  So yes, when they are iterated, they will come out differently, and therefore the two const are not the same and thus not identical().

Comment: See also https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Set-class.html. "Iterating over elements of a set may be either unordered or ordered in some way. A [HashSet](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-collection/HashSet-class.html) is unordered, which means that its iteration order is unspecified,
[LinkedHashSet](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html) iterates in the insertion order of its elements, and
a sorted set like [SplayTreeSet](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html) iterates the elements in sorted order."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart sets are *ordered* in the sense that if you use their `iterator`, you get elements in *some* order. That order may or may not be predictable. The order is unspecified for sets in general, but some `Set` implementations may choose to specify a specific ordering.

The one thing that is required is that the ordering of a set doesn't change unless the set changes. So, if you iterate the same set twice, without changing it in-between, you get the same ordering — whatever it is.

- `LinkedHashSet` promises insertion ordering.
- `SplayTreeSet` promises comparator ordering.
- Constant set literals promise *source ordering* (first occurrence if the same value occurs more than once). They're like immutable `LinkedHashSet`s.